# Allow object literal, prevent string

Tags: typescript

The following works:

```
class Foo {
    public bar(param: {}): void {

    }
}

let foo: Foo = new Foo();
foo.bar(""); // Ok
foo.bar({test: ""}); // Also Ok
```

Is it possible to change the method signature of `bar` so that:

```
foo.bar({somePropertyWhichIdontKnowTheName: ""}); // Would be ok
foo.bar(""); // Not Ok
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
class Foo {
    public bar(param: { [key: string]: any }): void {

    }
}
```

Or:

```
type FooBarParams = {
    [key: string]: any
}

class Foo {
    public bar(param: FooBarParams): void {

    }
}
```

And then:

```
let foo: Foo = new Foo();
foo.bar(""); // Error: Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type { [key: string]: any }
foo.bar({test: ""}); // ok
```